# Error in require(biwavelet)

Tags: r, wavelet

I have just downloaded `biwavelet` package but when trying to open it in R version 3.1.2 i get this error message:

```
> library(biwavelet)
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘spam’
  Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘biwavelet’
```

It only happens with this package. Any clues about what is the problem here?

Comment: How did you install `biwavelet`? If you downloaded the package and used something like `R CMD INSTALL`, then you'd have to manage the dependencies yourself. If instead you try re-installing from within `R` via `install.packages("biwavelet")`, the dependency graph will be handled for you. (E.g. `spam` might depend on other packages, which depend on other packages, so forth and so on...)

Comment: Thank you both. I have installed it via install.packages("biwavelet",dep=T). @MrFlick, your suggestion solved the problem! thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be missing a dependency somehow. Just run

```
install.packages("spam")
```

to install the missing package.